# Remove ?tmpl=component&print=1 from the end of URL

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect:

```
www.domain.com/someword/xxxx-other-words?tmpl=component&print=1
```

To:

```
www.domain.com/someword/xxxx-other-words
```

This is the code I'm using in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}    "?tmpl=component&print=1" [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)  /$1? [R=301,L]
```

Which is returning a `500 IS Error`

Comment: Have you set the `RewriteEngine on` ?

Comment: Are you using `apache` ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using apache and I have other redirects working well in .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you forget to enable mod_rewrite (you can check it in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`) or `AllowOverride` directive is absent.

I did (on fresh debian/jessie):

```
# apt-get install apache2
# a2enmod rewrite
  add AllowOverride into /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
# systemctl restart apache2
```

Your site-config should have `AllowOverride All` inside <Directory>, something like that

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        <Directory "/var/www/html">
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and /var/www/html/.htaccess (for default site)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} tmpl=component&print=1 [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using rewrite rules if you have apache.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)(\?tmpl=component&print=1) $1 [R=301,L]
```

**[Regex101 Demo for replacement only.](https://regex101.com/r/mV6oP4/1)**